# Flutter how to print value pass through screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing value between 2 screens I need to know how can I simply print value?

This is how I am sending value

```
onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (_) => ViewPostScreen(
                   id: id,
                  ),
                 ),
               );
            },
```

This is my second page

```
class ViewPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  ViewPostScreen({Key key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewPostScreenState createState() => _ViewPostScreenState();
}

class _ViewPostScreenState extends State<ViewPostScreen> {
}
```

I need to print the value of `id` in `_ViewPostScreenState` I try with simple print but showing error anyone can help?

[image]

Comment: post error message

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using `print` inside a method rather at the class level. Create a method and then use print inside it.

```
void method() {
  print(...);
}
```

---

Full solution:

```
class ViewPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  ViewPostScreen({Key key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewPostScreenState createState() => _ViewPostScreenState();
}

class _ViewPostScreenState extends State<ViewPostScreen> {
  void method() {
    print(widget.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: can I use this method in _ViewPostScreenState?

Comment: Yes, you can, I just added full solution. Please take a look.

Comment: actually he doesn't need to create method `method` to access widget.id from state class as  mentioned in your answer

Comment: Yes you're right, he can do that inside any method, I just created a standalone method to make things look easy.

Comment: Thanks. also, I need to call a method in initState(). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (_) {
print(id); // print here
                      return ViewPostScreen(
                       id: id,
                      );
                   }
                 ),
               );
            },
```

Comment: need to print on other page

Answer (score 0):

You can access the widget's attributes from the State using `widget`

```
print(widget.id.toString());
```

You cannot call the print function in the class body. It needs to be within a function. You can use initState as it is the first function that runs.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.id.toString());
}
```

Note that you will also need a build method in your State class